# How to change a field with a date with AutoIt?

Tags: date, autoit

I am trying to automate a report with AutoIt and every day I have to go in and change 2 fields to today's date. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Comment: You should give some more information. What kind of report? Where are these two date fields stored? Which controls are used for the dates?

Answer (score 0):

Explain your question further
The thing i found was **_DateAdd** function
https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_DateAdd.htm

Comment: To have everytime, if the script runs, the right date: use macros `@MON, @MDAY, @YEAR`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `_NowDate()` function. It will take the current date from your computer.

You can read its Documentation on: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_NowDate.htm